# How to get the file type after file extension gets removed

Tags: c#

I got stuck getting the file type of a file which does not have an extension. Consider the following scenario: I have an `.xlsx` file **sample.xlsx**; its extension gets removed so now the file name is **sample**.

How can I identify that it is an `.xlsx` file without having its extension?

Comment: Why do you remove the extension if you still need to know it? Use the `System.IO.Path` class, for example: `string fn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path)` or `string ex = Path.GetExtension(path)`.

Comment: Why not take note of the extension before you remove it

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess op stores file without an extension.

Comment: You can check if it starts with `50 4B 03 04`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: my question was somewhat rhetorical, why don't he store the type alongside before he loses this information or why can't he store the full path instead?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, maybe storing the extension before removing it from the file is out of his control. Think of a file recovery utility, that is completely unaware of the previous state of the file.

Comment: @TimSchmelter As I understood he doesn't remove it. He says *its extension gets removed*, so if he gets file without extension it is going to be hard to find, if he removes it then your comment is likely to help.

Comment: Actully I have a .pgp file when I Unpgp that file i have tp pass file extention but I do not know that file extention so how can I pass extension

Comment: I have downloaded a file from ftp server the file was as a .txt file but actually it is .xls file so how can i determine the actual file type. I have googled a lot but could not find a solution.

Comment: You can check [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-deflist.html) definitions list.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses the file extension to determine the file type.  There are OSs that store a mime-type for each file, but Windows does not.

By removing the extension, you've removed the only data you had on that.

You **can** *infer* the type based on contents, but that's hard to write unless you just have a couple of possible filestypes to choose from.

Comment: Can you help me doing so. Can you share a code to resolve this. I have googled a lot but could not find the solution.

Comment: Third party libraries that check headers and content to deduce file type.

Like these outdated ones:
File.TypeChecker -> https://github.com/AJMitev/FileTypeChecker
File -> https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm
Jhove -> https://jhove.openpreservation.org/

See this post too:
https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36519/determine-file-type-from-its-content-not-trusting-the-extension